# Except Sql query in Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using the bellow sql to get available room:

```
select rooms.number  
from rooms  

EXCEPT 

(SELECT rooms.number 
 FROM dbo.Bookings 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Rooms ON Extent1.RoomId = dbo.Rooms.Id 
 WHERE 
     (Bookings.StartDate <= '2014-12-01') 
     AND (Bookings.EndDate >= '2016-12-05') 
)
```

Could you please help me to convert it to Linq? (like "var list= from a in db...."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is too generic.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var start = DateTime.ParseExact("20141201", 
                          "yyyyMMdd", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
var end = DateTime.ParseExact("20141205", 
                          "yyyyMMdd", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var list = dbContext.Rooms
    .Except(dbContext.Bookings
        .Where(e => e.StartDate >= start)
        .Where(e => e.EndDate <= end)
        .Select(e => e.Room))
    .SELECT(e => e.Number)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad Akbari. Thanks su much!!

Comment: Its my pleasure, if my  answer is ok, plz tick answer.